# How to create an API only user

Tags: api, user-management

I want to create an "API Only" user but can't find the checkbox to do that. I can see "API Enabled" as one of the checkboxes on the profile and permission set pages but I think that's different. How can I create an API only user ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an option called "API only" below "API enabled" in profile. If you are looking in developer edition it isn't available but it's there in enterprise edition.

Comment: this is also available in developer edition :)

Comment: Oh is it? I checked in my developer edition but this option was not showing up in profile.

Comment: yeah it is available :)

Comment: My bad :(  
I have deleted my answer .

Comment: No problem my dear friend

Comment: I only see API enabled and not API only. I have developer edition so I think Seth is right.

Comment: Mark it as an answer if you find it useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a permission not a special user. You can create a new API only user by setting permission at profile level:-

- Create a new User.
- Create a new Profile or clone existing one
- In new profile at **Administrative section** check the checkbox "*Api Only User*" and **Save**.
- You have created an API only user

> When you check the API User checkbox, it restrict the permission of UI
>   based login, you can't use credentials to actually log into the
>   Salesforce instance. It count against API user license.

Comment: Is this available in developer edition?

Comment: @Sethu Developer edition doesn't have this.

Comment: @Sethu Developer edition doesn't have administrative section also.

Comment: We do have the section called "Administrative Permission" in developer edition. Are you referring to some other section?

Comment: In dev edition we have system permission instead of administrative permission. Just checked Manage users &gt; Profile &gt; System administrator @Sethu

Comment: Strange. I checked for both standard user and system administrator and I could see only the section called Administrative permissions

Answer (score 5):

For those that do see it, if you are looking at a dev org created from an existing EE org, you should have it. However, if you are creating a brand new dev org that is not connected/related to an existing EE org, it is not there.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers here: you will not see the "API Only" option for the cheaper "Salesforce Platform" licenses. You need to have a profile attached to the full "Salesforce" license for the "API Only" option to appear.

Source: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdf77UAB/api-only-platform-user